# how to display os.environ.get value in ubuntu using python/django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

i have the following OS"

```
(env) ubuntu@ip-xxxxxx:~/test/test_app$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

now to set the env variable i have accessed `nano ~/.profile` and edited the file with:

```
export TEST="johndoe"
```

then exited nano and did `chmod a+x ~/.profile` and `~/.profile` to apply the changes

now in **django** views.py when i try to access the variable:

## views.py

```
...
import os

@api_view(["GET"])
def index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        env_var = os.environ.get("TEST")
        context = {"response": "Welcome: {}".format(env_var)}
        return Response(context)
```

## result

```
{
    "response": "Welcome: None"
}
```

PS: I dont' intend to use any os variable in the **views.py**, i was just testing it there so i can use it in the **settings.py**

Is there any reason why the value `None` is returned (why it's not picking up the actual value)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you log out and back in before you ran this code? I mean from your console session; e.g. reboot the machine so that the .profile is actually loaded?

Comment: @velis yes, i m using `apache` as a server so i am wondering if the server is not picking it up actually

Comment: @velis yes, it was the issue, should have updated server `envvars`

Comment: Gr8 to hear you got it working